# Why VGG16 Outperforms VGG19?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, classification, cnn, vgg16

I built VGG16 and VGG19 models using transfer learning. As far as I know, VGG19 has more convolutional layers and it is more complex, VGG16 performs better in terms of accuracy and loss. I can't understand how possible is that. What are the possible reasons? Any explanation is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One possible answer is that `VGG19` overfits the data, whereas `VGG16` does not. This means that it is simple enough for `VGG19` to perform perfectly on the training data and poorly on the test/validation, as it does not generalize